# The true proportion is within two standard deviations of the sample proportion

Tags: distributions, proportion

A [Khan Academy tutorial](https://youtu.be/hlM7zdf7zwU?t=389) says

> If there's a 95% chance that the sample proportion is within two standard deviations of the true proportion, that's equivalent to that there's a 95% chance that the true proportion is within two standard deviations of the sample proportion.

Is this just a practical rule or a rule was verified theoretically?

I understand the basic idea of [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule). I don't understand how do I apply that rule to the sampling distribution.

which seems to indicate that, given (the remaining of this post is my understanding about the "rule")

> the following image represents the distribution of population, the center of it represents the true proportion, the sample proportion falls within the red + blue area

then

> when the image represents sampling distribution of sample proportion, the true proportion falls within the red + blue area

Is my understanding right?

[image]

Comment: The first quotation lies somewhere on the spectrum between confusion and nonsense.  The rest involves so many assumptions and approximations that it would take an extensive reply to address them all.  Consider researching the "68-95-99.7 Rule," the "Central Limit Theorem," and the concept of the "sampling distribution" of a statistic.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. Is "confusion and nonsense" some kind of metaphor? It just indicate the first quotation does not make any sense, right?

Comment: I chose those words carefully and meant them as defined in English.  The potential *confusion* is between an underlying distribution and the distribution of a sample statistic. The *nonsense* attaches to treating the "true proportion" as if it were a random variable.

Comment: @whuber "confusion" seems a plain English rather than a statistics/probability term, what does that mean?

Comment: @whuber Is [my understanding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/459442/280357) about your comments correct?